# calling url from java class one after another one for logging in and another for web service call

Tags: java, web-services, url, pentaho

I am able to log in to pentaho user console by calling

```
protocal&hostname/pentaho/j_spring_security_check?j_username=joe&j_password=password
```

from java class
after that I want to call web service call with url
`protocal&hostname/pentaho/SolutionRepositoryService?component=createNewFolder&solution=New_Report&path=&name=suzy_reports&desc=suzy_reports` that java class itself
but on calling second url it's giving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: protocal&hostname/pentaho/Login;jsessionid=F096F1C25268
D1A795A55892511D6506
```

but both url are working alone fine

-is there any way to have single url for both calls?
-calling first url and having session stored so that it doesn't ask for authentication for second?
or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 mean Unauthorized.

I think you need to support session at your side. After authorisation server create a session your client does not support.

You can try use HttpClient - it support session and cookies.

1. Do first call with HttpClient to autorize (will create a session and put cookies values)
2. Do second call with same HttpClient instance